# How to resolve uninitialized constant Search:: error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an advanced search/filter for my Appointment model related to car maintenance, where the tables in schema.rb for each are:

```
  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "VIN"
    t.string "owner_email"
    t.string "date"
    t.string "time"
    t.string "reason"
    t.string "parts_needed"
    t.string "hours_needed"
    t.string "cost"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "VIN"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "after_date"
    t.string "before_date"
    t.string "time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

In my search.rb model I define the search function:

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord

    def search_appointments
        appointments = Appointment.all
        # appointments = appointments.where("VIN LIKE ?", VIN) if VIN.present? GIVES ERROR
        appointments = appointments.where("owner_email LIKE ?", email) if email.present?
        appointments = appointments.where("date >= ?", after_date) if after_date.present?
        appointments = appointments.where("date <= ?", before_date) if before_date.present?
        if !time=="Any"
            appointments = appointments.where("time LIKE ?", time) if time.present?
        end

        return appointments
    end
end
```

And then in my show.html.erb display the resulting filter:

```
<h2 align="center">Search Results</h2>
</br>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <% if @search.search_appointments.empty? %>
        <p> No Appointments Fit This Search</p>

    <% else %>
        <%= @search.search_appointments.each do |a| %>

        Email: <%= a.owner_email%> </br>
        Date: <%= a.date%> </br>
        Time: <%= a.time%> </br>
        VIN: <%= a.VIN %> </br>

        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </br>
    <%= link_to 'Return', @search, method: :delete %>
</div>
```

Things work fine except for the first filter attempt in the search.rb model, the line that is commented out. If I uncomment the line and run a search, that line is highlighted and I get an error:

```
uninitialized constant Search::VIN
```

I don't understand why this is happening as all other filters are working just fine. I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Search controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @search = Search.new
    end

    def create
        @search = Search.create(search_params)
        redirect_to @search
    end

    def show
        @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @search = Search.find(params[:id])
        @search.destroy

        redirect_to admin_path
    end

    def search_params
        params.require(:search).permit(:VIN, :email, :after_date, :before_date, :time)
    end
end
```

Where my 'new' page is a form where the user fills in the filter parameters and then clicks a submit button to take them to the show page that lists the filtered appointments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference `VIN` in `appointments.where("VIN LIKE ?", VIN)` ruby is looking for a constant because it is uppercase. In order to access your attribute you will need to reference `self.VIN` or change the column name to be lowercase (recommended).

Option 1: `appointments = appointments.where("VIN LIKE ?", self.VIN) if self.VIN.present?`

Option 2:

- Change the `VIN` column to `vin`
- `appointments = appointments.where("vin LIKE ?", vin) if vin.present?`

Comment: I went with the first option but that gave me the error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Searches#
show. --- PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "vin" does not exist.
And it seemed to point to the first VIN in the line

Comment: Is there a similar way to scope out the first VIN like you did with the second @weilandia? I tried Appointment.VIN and appointments.VIN but those did not seem to work.

Comment: @AJ.N the `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "vin"` means you did not run a migration to change the column.  These docs can help you with that: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html.  If you want to keep "VIN" as the column, you will have to reference it as `self.VIN` when accessing it from an instance of `Appointment`. You could define a method so that you can reference it as `vin` (i.e. `def vin; self.VIN; end`)
but that is not necessary and I recommend against it.

Comment: You could also do something like `alias_attribute :vin, :VIN` in the `Appointment` model, but again if you can change the column name, I'd recommend that.

Comment: I get what you're saying but the table for appointments has existed for a long time and has worked everywhere else, so I'm sure it was migrated. That's why I'm confused by this error and trying alias_attribute or defining the vin function doesn't fix the issue. It gives the same error each time saying the column does not exist when I'm sure it does. That's why i was asking for a way to scope it as it doesn't seem to be looking in the right place..

Comment: @AJ.N I misspoke in the comments above. I was commenting as though `VIN` was an attribute on `Appointment` but it's on `Search`.  So the `alias_attribute` would have to be in the `Search` model. I'm not sure why you're getting `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "vin"` but if you share the updated `Search` model and the relevant parts of `schema.rb` it might be clearer.

Comment: As a side note, when looking closer at your code I realized you were persisting searches -- Is persistence of every search a requirement? If not I would use a PORO to handle your searching, something like `@search = AppointmentSearcher.new(search_params)` where `AppointmentSearcher` is just a ruby class that takes search params, searches and memoizes the results to be used in the view.

Comment: I fixed the the error by changing the line to appointments = appointments.where('"VIN" LIKE ?', self.VIN) if self.VIN.present? Thanks so much for all the help! I do not need it to be persistent and was worried about that, which line exactly would I change to using AppointmentSearcher that would fix this? I added my search controller code at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @AJ.N that's a longer conversation. I'd recommend looking into 'service objects' generally. Here's a couple resources, but there are tons: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/service-objects-explained-simply-for-ruby-on-rails-5-a8cc42a5441f, https://medium.flatstack.com/query-object-in-ruby-on-rails-56ea434365f0